# bootstrap basic grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

In an attempt to learn responsive web design, I am teaching myself how to design with bootstrap.  I have created a basic grid; the code for the grid is shown below.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 red01">span6</div>
  <div class="span6 green01">span6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body { padding: 0px; }
.red01 { background: #ff0000; }
.green01 { background: #00ff00; }
```

I can see the two divs on my web page, but my problem is with how they are aligned.  I'd like to align them horizontally across my laptop's screen.  I've tried fiddling with this, but can't get it to work.  Could anyone please lend their expertise?

Comment: `display: inline-block` or `float: left` will; make the widths `50%` and they'll take up half of the space each

Comment: This didn't help.  Wouldn't two span6's be 50%?

Comment: @JaPerk14 plz check solution and let me know if ya need any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [JSfiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/fez34/)

See the result here [Result of 2 col](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/fez34/show)

```
  <div class="container">  
       <div class="row">  
          <div class="span12">  
             <h1>Bootstrap 12 col spanning full page</h1>   
   </div>
           <div class="span6">  
              <p> Paragraph test col1</p>   
       </div>  
       <div class="span6">  
               <p> Paragraph test col2.</p>   
        </div>  
       </div>  
    </div>
```

`.container class` -> Its a wrapper with fixed width , predefined in bootstrap.css .

`.container-fluid` -> which is fluid wrapper

`.row` --> This class is built to contain a row of columns. Each new row creates a new zone for laying out columns as desired.

Comment: What exactly is the container class?  I didn't see it in the documentation.

Comment: I'm also noticing that you're nesting elements within each other?  Why are you doing this?

Comment: @JaPerk14 I hope that answers your question

Comment: I have one last question:  When I set a bg-color to container, and both the rows, the two rows hang outside the container.  Is this normal?  Should I provide an image?

Comment: provide me an image or jsfiddle

Comment: I had trouble with print screen, so I created the image through paint.  What I'm talking about is how these divs aren't perfectly aligned nor are they contained within the container.  It seems that the left div is poking out of the container.

Comment: Sorry there was a extra div in the html markup , I accidently inserted a new row div which caused the issue .. Check the jsfiddle and the example.. a vote up will be greatly appreciated